# Measure packet latency / drop between ingress and egress interface of a rate-limiting pass-through host

Tags: linux, latency, tc, packetloss

Somewhere between my sender and receiver, there is host explicitly limiting my transfer rate.

I know it's a Linux host. The ingress interface for my traffic is `eth0` and the egress interface is `eth1`. The rate limiter is most probably realized *somehow* using Linux' traffic control (`tc`), but I don't know the details.

From an earlier [offline comparison](https://serverfault.com/questions/1011155) between pcap files recorded at `eth0` and `eth1` interfaces, I know that the rate limiter adds significant packet latency (up to 15 seconds!) and packet loss (up to 16%), when I try to *push through* as much data as possible, using `iperf`.

All traffic is TCP/IP. Source IP, destination IP and destination port are known and constant. Only the source port changes between consecutive flows.

**Given (root) access, is there a way to do a *live measurement* of the packet latency and drop counters / rates? Or recorded to a file as time series data?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could. At first, you should watch your `tc` statistics output (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96804/tc-show-output-explanation)
Further, you could watch your network traffic flow with any network load utilities - `iftop`, `iptraf`,`nethogs`,`bandwhich`, etc.

P.S. And I'd recommend to review tc configuration of `tc` - it's better to use *shaping* than hard *rate-limit*. A good difference explanation is here: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/quality-of-service-qos/qos-policing/19645-policevsshape.html